# Can I write this in verilog (Calling a function with indirect arguments)?

Tags: function, verilog

Suppose in a program, I write this function for dividing 2 values:

```
function [63:0] DIV_VAL;     // Function for Multiplying two values 32 bits.
input [63:0] a, b;
always @ (a or b)
    DIV_VAL = a / b; 
endfunction
```

Then later in the code I want to call this function with input Znk1 BUT rotating them 16 bits and 12 bits (first and second argument of the function). Moreover, since the function DIV_VAL answer me with a number of 64 bits, I only want to 32 bits from it, to be loaded to NC_1: Like this.

```
NC_1 = DIV_VAL [31:0] (Znk1 << 16, Znk1 >> 12) ;
```

Is this allowed, does it work? I'm not sure about the order also.

Second question: As alternative for this situation, a friend told me I can define some registers like a, b and use them to do something like this:

```
a = Znk1 << 16;
b = Znk1 >> 12;
NC_1 = DIV_VAL [31:0] (a, b);
NC_1 = NC_1[31:0];
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't put an `always` block inside a `function`. Your function should be:

```
function [63:0] DIV_VAL;     // Function for Multiplying two values 32 bits.
  input [63:0] a, b;
  DIV_VAL = a / b; 
endfunction
```

or as you've written using an old-fashioned style, perhaps:

```
function [63:0] DIV_VAL (input [63:0] a, b);     // Function for Multiplying two values 32 bits.
  DIV_VAL = a / b; 
endfunction
```

You can then call the function with expressions in the function call, if you wish:

```
NC_1 = DIV_VAL (Znk1 << 16, Znk1 >> 12) ;
```

but truncating the return value explicitly as you were doing is not allowed. But you don't need to truncate explicitly, Verilog will do it implicitly. (Hence no `[31:0]` in the above code.)